# Switching multiple outputs with a single input

Tags: switches, integrated-circuit

Here's my problem. I need a way to switch between two inputs of four signals each (four 5V lines and 4 3V3 lines). They need to be switched together, and ideally with a single jumper or an electrical signal. I know there are many ways to accomplish this (e.g. by 4-sets of 3-pole jumpers), but I'm wondering what you think the most efficient way is.

To put it in the context of the image below: depending on whether S is on or off, the outputs O1..3 should be connected with A1..3 or B1..3. What part does this most efficiently?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSuqqq.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: have you heard of a multiplexer ?

Comment: Your diagram seems to be at odds with your words. Can you clarify exactly what the inputs are and how many outputs there are?

Comment: I assume either there are four (text) or three (diagram) lines for each voltage. Other than that A's (say 5V) and B's (say 3V3) clearly go to the O's with S as the select.

Comment: I can't believe I did not think of a mux. Too much FPGA work = forgetting there are real world logic elements. Thank you all. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a simple quad 2:1 multiplexer. Something like a 74157 if I understand you correctly, it should operate okay at those voltages but it would be best to check yourself.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You also can use 2 number 74573 latch .with eabling each IC you has it's input on the output.Outputs are coupled .
[image]

Comment: That isn't exactly the most simple way is it.